# Does the order in css file play a role?

Tags: css, menu, nested-lists

In my case I have, simplified a nested list and enclosing div, i cant change it, it's created by drupal menu.

I want to clone the menu of a hardcoded site  (*edit* removed link)

How would i "embed" the boxes ( ul li ul li items ) in the submenu, is it possible in just a list in block display? Do i need a z-index for them?  Or float? Is float even possible on list items?

In general i understand the cascading thing but still do hard in writing css with few repeates. Some tips for shortening would be nice.

My primary question for now is why the style of the last entry (marked) is overwritten. Does the order in file play a role?

```
#block-system-main-menu .content {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#block-system-main-menu div ul li {
    width: 207px;
    margin: 4px 0px;
}

#block-system-main-menu div ul li {
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    background: url(/sites/all/themes/schott/menuitembg.gif);
}

#block-system-main-menu div ul li .active-trail {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(/sites/all/themes/schott/menuitembg_p.png);
}

div ul li ul li.leaf {   /* both styles are overwritten */
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(/sites/all/themes/schott/subitem_passive.gif);
}
```

Comment: hm why the last entry is overwritten i understand, I removed the id in front and forgot about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last CSS rule written is the one that is used, but specificity takes priority over cascading.

An article on specificity: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

So `#block-system-main-menu div ul li .active-trail` is the most specific and will overwrite other rules.

Answer (score 2):

yes, the order of CSS definitely plays a role. Anything declared after a style overwrites the previous one. Also, if you want to overwrite default styles of some sort, include them after the default ones (whether you write them in the same file, or just do a meta link to your own stylesheet).

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
#block-system-main-menu div ul li ul li.leaf {
```

I'm slightly confused by what you're asking, but in general, if you have two identical rules, the later will be applied.  However, if rules are not identical, the more specific rule will take precedence.

Edit: sorry, I can see you just figured that out